# PySide6, adding and action in the mainwindow menu that opens an existing file

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside6

(1)

mainwindow.py

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QMdiSubWindow, QWidget
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from location.widget_location import location_widget


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.actionLocation.triggered.connect(self.new_location)


    def new_location(self, location_widget):
```

```
    print("todo: open new location widget")
```

##this is the code i am using to run mainwindow ui file.
and here def new_location is the funtion that call the already existing location file as a subwindow.

---

(2)

i wanted too make the action, when we click on the menu option "location" a new subwindow opens with ui file of location.

widget_location.py

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from ui_location import Ui_Form

class location_widget(QWidget, Ui_Form):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app_location = QApplication(sys.argv)
    local = location_widget()
    local.show()
    sys.exit(app_location.exec())
```

this is the code i am using to run the "location" ui file

---

how can i complete the code (2)

i tried this code:~

```
def new_location(self):
        #print("todo: open new location widget")
        subwindow = QMdiSubWindow()
        subwindow.setWidget(Ui_Form().setupUi(Ui_Form()))
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(subwindow)
        subwindow.show()
```

it gives error,
error give: line 24, in setupUi
if not Form.objectName():
AttributeError: 'Ui_Form' object has no attribute 'objectName'

the line that is giving error in ui_location (thr ui file of location_widget )

```
def setupUi(self, Form):
    if not Form.objectName():
        Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
```

well this the main error i am encountering
and i checked it in the QT designer the object name is Form, but how to use it?
or either it says: no moule named ui_location

when i try

```
    def new_location(self, location_widget):
        print("todo: open new location widget")
        local = location_widget()
        local.setupUi(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(local)
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(local)
        self.local.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def new_location(self):
    self.local = Ui_Form()
    self.local_widget = QWidget()
    self.local.setupUi(self.local_widget)
    self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.local_widget)
    self.local_widget.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**